# Is there an interface in Vaadin14 to create custom Component instead of extending Component class?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I want to create a custom component in Vaadin. But instead of extending it from a Component class I tried as below

public class MyMapComponent extends LMap implements Component {
}

I get error as

```
getId()' in 'com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent' clashes with 'getId()' in 'com.vaadin.flow.component.Component'; attempting to use incompatible return type.
```

How to resolve this error? What is the best way to achieve it?

Am I going in correct direction? I want add the LMap as component in Vaadin 14. Since v-leaflet does not support above Vaadin 8, I am trying MPR for which I am trying to add LMap as component in vaadin flow.

Answer (score 5):

In Vaadin 8 and older, `Component` is an interface and `AbstractComponent` is an abstract class implementing that interface. Creating your own completely custom implement of the `Component` interface without using `AbstractComponent` as the base class is rarely feasible because of all the internal bookkeeping that is needed.

In Vaadin 10 and newer, this is taken one step further. There is no separate interface with only one viable implementation but instead, `Component` itself is an abstract class.

Furthermore, it seems like you're trying to mix the Vaadin 8 `AbstractComponent` and the Vaadin 14 `Component` base types in the same class hierarchy. This cannot work since they are explicitly incompatible with each other.

The `v-leaflet` add-on is not compatible with newer version of Vaadin, but the author of that add-on recommends using https://vaadin.com/directory/component/leafletmap-for-vaadin instead.